# Excel: how to use this formula MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$2,C2)),Z$2)...as array?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$2,C2)),Z$2),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$3,C2)),Z$3),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$4,C2)),Z$4),.......
```

I want to match each of my string(C) with pattern(containing wildcards) in the next column(T) for returning the max value of the same row in column (Z).

For each cell in c column, I have to search more than a hundred pattern and found it is too difficult to type the formula from row 2 to some hundred. Is there any way to use this formula as array?

Comment: What is your last row? What cell is this formula being used? As I understand it, you have to perform this same function all over again for C3, then again for C4, all the way to the end. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. My last row is 158. To use the formula as mentioned is too long and too easy to make a mistake.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using (e.g. 2007, 2010, 2013)?

Answer (score 1):

If it can be reasonably assumed tat you are operating under Excel 2010 or higher, then the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) would make a quick formula.

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ((C2:C9<>"")*(Z2:Z9))/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2:C9, T2:T9)), 1)
```

[image: AGGREGATE for conditional MAX]

This is actually using the [LARGE subfunction](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) of AGGREGATE. If you wanted the second, third, etc. maximum value then simply replace the last *1* used as the *k* parameter. Example:

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, ((C$2:C$9<>"")*(Z$2:Z$9))/ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$2:C$9, T$2:T$9)), ROW(1:1))
```

Fill that down for the first, second, third, etc values. A return of *0* indicates no more matching values.

¹<sub>AGGREGATE was introduced with Excel 2010. If you have a previous version, post a comment and another solution may be possible.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA. To use the below code, follow the steps that follow.

```
Public Sub generateFormula()
    Dim s as String
    Dim i as Integer
    s = "=MAX("
    For i = 2 to 158
        s = s & "IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T$" & i & ",C2)),Z$" & i & ")," 
    Next
    s = Left(s, Len(s)-1) & ")"
    Range("A2").Formula = s
End Sub
```

- Copy the code above
- Open your workbook
- Press Alt+F11 to open the VBE window
- In the menu select Insert -> Module
- Paste the code into the VBE window
- Change 100 to the last row you want to include
- Change "A2" to the cell you want the formula to go into
- Press Alt+F11 to close the VBE window
- Press Alt+F8 to open the Macro window
- The macro we created should be the only one listed (if not select it)
- Click Run